# Flask with Celery - workers exit with exitcode1

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have a flask app with celery. 
 
When I am running the worker as follows:

```
celery -A app.celery worker
```

I get the following output

```
 -------------- celery@local-pc v3.1.22 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         app:0x483e668
- ** ---------- .> transport:   mongodb://localhost:27017/app
- ** ---------- .> results:     mongodb://localhost:27017/app
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[2016-03-08 15:52:05,587: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@local-pc ready.
[2016-03-08 15:52:08,855: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-8' pid:9720 exited with 'exitcode 1'
[2016-03-08 15:52:08,855: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-7' pid:11940 exited with 'exitcode 1'
[2016-03-08 15:52:08,856: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-6' pid:13120 exited with 'exitcode 1'
...
```

It goes endlessly and the CPU raises to 100%.

the relevant configuration is:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/app'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/'
CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS = {
    'database': 'app',
    'taskmeta_collection': 'my_taskmeta_collection',
}
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('app.tasks', )
CELERYD_FORCE_EXEC = True
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

my project structure is:

```
proj/
    config.py
    app/
        __init__.py
        tasks.py
        views.py
```

this is how I configured my celery in ___init___.py":

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

celery = make_celery(app)
```

this is what I have in `tasks.py`

```
from app import celery


@celery.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b
```

**update**

When I remove the following line from the config file the worker does not exit

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('app.tasks', )
```

but I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python34\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer.py", line 456, in on_task_received
    strategies[name](message, body,
KeyError: 'app.tasks.add_together'
```

Comment: where are your tasks defined? i.e. what is in `app.celery.py` ?

Comment: In tasks.py I have the common add_numbers example

Comment: I don't have app.celery.py I created a celery object in app.__init__.py as I showed in the question

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? What does this ContextTask do?

Comment: This is taken from Flask's documentation http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/

Comment: can you show `app.tasks.py` ?

Comment: @scytale I added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the official Celery web site http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/getting-started/brokers/mongodb.html

States that when using mongoDB as a broker, you are doing it at your own risk.

> Using MongoDB
>
> Experimental Status
>
> The MongoDB transport is in need of improvements in many areas and there are several open bugs. Unfortunately we don’t have the resources or funds required to improve the situation, so we’re looking for contributors and partners willing to help.

To test if that is not what generates your problem, try to use redis, or rabbitMQ as brokers.